# UK Visa refused twice, should I give up?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, applications, translations

I am an Algerian citizen, working as a computer scientist in Paris.

I have been refused a tourist visa for UK for the second time despite having strong applying documents, good income, and a rich travel history(I gave all my boarding passes that includes flights to +10 EU countries + canadian visa)
The reasons given seem absurd to me, and I really think they just don't want me to visit UK independently from given documents.

** You state that you intend to visit the UK for 4 days and propose tourism.**
Am I not free to decide how long I want to visit the country depending on my budget and holidays given by me employer ?

**In support of this you have submitted your payslips, letter confirming employment and bank statements in French. It is unclear whether your employment is permanent, temporary or fixed term and whether your employer has granted you leave for the stated duration of your trip.** I could have agreed with this argument, if I haven't applied with a colleague that has gave the same proof of employment as me(which was in french), and had his visa. Furthermore the visa application required documents are around 50 pages long, and it costs around 50€ to translate one paper, which means I have to spend 2500€ for translating document, this is ridiculous ! For my first application that has been refused too, all documents were in french and this wasn't the reason of the refusal(it was because I applied during summer as a student and I didn't have my new student card yet), they were able to extract information from the application's documents.

**I note that the bank statements you have submitted do not correspond with the income you have stated on your Visa Application Form (VAF) or your payslips.**
This is I think the worst reason, some months I'm paid 2000€ instead of 2100€ because it was a month with one less working day(30 instead of 31)

**The bank documents you have provided show large credits not commensurate with your documented income in the time leading up to your visa application. There is no explanation provided regarding the origin of these funds. I am not satisfied these funds are genuinely available for your use and have been provided to you for the sole purpose of obtaining an entry clearance for the UK.**
I don't know what to say about this, I have other accounts where that a use to transfer money to for savings. I don't know what more I can do to proof that these funds are mine, since they are here in my account for years.

Considering the refusal reasons, the only document I can translate is my certificate of employment and income given by my employer, and since this refusal(one month ago) I have been given an USA visa. So, with these two new elements, is it worth applying again or should I give up ? I'm afraid they will think I'm a bit obsessed if I apply again(which is partially true because UK /Eire is the only part of Europe I haven't visited yet)

[image]
[image: refusal letter's second page]

Comment: Honestly - I would give up on the UK for now. Go to the Republic of Ireland if you want a holiday in the region.

Comment: One thing to add is that even despite the documents being in French, were a translation to be provided this application would likely sink anyway as the bank statement does not match the claimed employment. Do you have an explanation for it?

Comment: I don't, I dont understand what they are talking about. I reveice my salary every month on the account I showed. What I think they are talking about is that they saw large credits nit commensurate with the documented income. This could be due to two reasons : 
 1- I have saving accounts where I transfer founds from my salary every months, I dont know what I can do to show that this is not funds parking, I have provided statements for the whole 2017 year !.
2- My salary isn't fix, sometimes I work more and thus get paid more(or less if it's a 30 days month)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your visa was refused because, among other things, you failed to follow the instructions.

Your supporting documents must be in English and any document that is not in English will not be considered. Since all your supporting evidence was in French, none of it actually supported your application. The [visitor visa supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) is very clear on this.

> If you submit a document that is not in English or Welsh, it must be accompanied by a full translation that can be independently verified by the Home Office. Each translated document must contain:
>
> - confirmation from the translator that it is an accurate translation of the original
>   document
> - the date of the translation
> - the translator's full name and signature
> - the translator's contact details

You state that you had "strong applying documents" but, in effect, you had no documents at all. You also included irrelevant documents such as boarding passes for flights you've taken and visas for other countries. Nobody needs 50 pages of supporting documents for a four-day tourist visit. A letter from your employer saying that you work for them doesn't need to be more than a page, for example.

You have not been refused a visa because you proposed to be a tourist for four days (though I accept that a literal reading of the refusal letter suggests you have). Rather, the Entry Clearance Officer is stating the reason you applied for the visa because that determines what criteria you must satisfy. For example, if you had applied for a visa to do business in the UK, you would be expected to provide evidence of what that business is; if you had applied for a visa to make a study visit, you'd need to give evidence of your programme of study.

See also the answers at [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/92121/11491), which explain what you need to do beyond providing translations.

Comment: I joined a travel history as a supporting document, I was asked for it for canadian visa ans since it was available I add it as an "additional" document. The thing is, I think this is ridiculous to translate the whole documents, especially bank statements. This would easily cost between 2-3k € for the whole application. I don't think this is respectful at all, especially when other embassies accept documents in french and communicate in french(Hello USA, Canada, Argentina etc ...)

Comment: If you're applying for a UK visa, you need to supply the documents the UK wants, not the documents that Canada wants. I sympathise about the costs of translation but, ultimately, it's what the UK requires and that's the end of it. And you can hardly complain about the cost of translating documents that you were never asked to provide. Read the instructions and follow them. (Also, note that French is one of the official langauges of Canada -- of course they accept documents in French.)